# ThreeJS change camera to orthographic

Tags: reactjs, three.js, camera, orthographic, react-three-fiber

The default camera in react-three-fiber is perspective so that my rotating model distorts as it rotates.  I need an orthographic camera instead to avoid this.  The react-three-fiber documentation suggests that I can change the camera by including the statement in the canvas module:

```
"orthographic = false          // Creates an orthographic camera if true
```

But this statement doesn’t work = the compiler doesn’t like the equals sign.

The statement below IS accepted by the compiler but there is no noticeable difference to the distortion:
<Canvas style={{ background: "#171717", orthographic : true }}>

The npm documentation doesn' state specifically that the orthographic camera created in this way will replace the existing camera, or create a new camera.

There is a Set Default Camera statement

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
  <Canvas orthographic camera={{ zoom: 50, position: [0, 0, 100] }} >
    <ambientLight /> 
    <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
    <directionalLight intensity={4.16} />
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <YourModel />         // replace with name of function which creates your model
    </Suspense>
  </Canvas>
```